# Looping through two std::vectors using the same iterator

Tags: c++, vector

So, one of my classes has the following overload:

```
DVector &operator+=(DVector const &other) {
    if (vector.size() >= other.vector.size()) throw up; // lol.

    std::for_each(other.vector.begin(); other.vector.end(), [](DVector const &pass) {
        // huh?
    });
}
```

So, the idea is to sum every member of both vectors (uhm, every `DVector` instance contains a `std::vector<float>` member called `vector`), for example:

If I had one `DVector` containing a `vector` member containing the following floats: `11.0, 23.5, 12.3`, and then another one containing `14.0, 6.5, 7.7`, the sum of both should lead to the first vector holding `25.0, 25.0, 25.0`.

The question: is there any way to loop through both vectors and sum their members using only one iterator, assuming that the size of the vectors isn't a problem, or am I just forced to use a `for (auto x: vector.size())`?

Cheers, Julian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The is a std::transfom algorithm that take in two inputs and an output iterator.

I don't know how you specific vector design is consturcted but you should be able to modify the following for your needs.

```
 std::transform(input1.begin(), input1.end(),  //input1
                intput2.begin(),               //input2
                input1.begin(),                //output 
     [](double a, double b){
          return a+b;
     });
```

You can also have a different output iterator for you `operator +` also well.

Here are some references

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/

And when you have a different output a back_inserter is your friend:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter

Comment: There is no need for any different output iterator for `operator +`, the overload is as simple as applying `+=` between the two members of sum. Thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: Ok, but often when you implement operator += you are only a couple of steps of having a normal `+` was just trying to predict a likely next question. :)

Comment: Actually, I'm wondering whether there is any need to do a pass by-value?, wouldn't it be more effective to do a pass by-reference (and const), assuming that neither of the passed arguments will be modified?

Comment: And of course, if like most of us, your compiler doesn't yet support lambdas, there's `std::plus<double>` which will do exactly the above lambda does.

Comment: @JamesKanze: yep, but the OP used Lambda in their opening post so didn't feel the need to introduce std:: functors

Comment: @JulianBayardoSpadafora I assume you are talking about the lambda, for POD type passing by reference is MORE expensive than passing by reference (as it has to pass an address and unpack it).

Comment: @JamesKanze: Thanks for that, I didn't know `std::plus` existed!, still, I'm using g++ 4.5.3 which, according to [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) page, supports lambda functions (although I haven't yet tried to compile), also, this code is just to try and get back into C++.

@111111: uhm, I suppose you meant that passing by reference is more expensive than copying. Does the same apply to say, an structure which contains many POD-type members?

Comment: @111111 Yes.  I just mentioned it as an aside, because most people don't have the luxury of being able to use lambda yet.  (When you first get a new feature of that complexity, I'd be hesitant about using it in production code for quite a few years.  The first implementations of new, complex features are notoriously buggy.)

Comment: @JamesKanze the general advice is that any classes you write yourself (even if they just contain PODs) should be passed by const ref, however all POD's (int, double, char...) should be passed by value.

Comment: @111111 Not sure what I said to disagree with that.  Of course, it's not the convention of the standard library, where iterators and functional objects are normally passed by value (although they're usually class types).

Answer (score 2):

The iterator is tied to the container so you can't use a single iterator. You'll have to use an index or two separate iterators.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding your needs correctly:

```
std::transform(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), vec2.begin(), vec1.begin(),
    [](float lhs, float rhs) {
        return lhs + rhs;
    });
```